# Python Pandas Indexing Reform

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV table with data similar to below:

```
Customer    Product    Quantity

C1          P1         2
C2          P1         3
C1          P2         4
C3          P2         1
C3          P1         0
C2          P2         5
```

I would like to convert it to the format below:

```
Customer    P1    P2

C1          2     4
C2          3     5
C3          1     0
```

I know I can import the file using pandas as below:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv')
```

However, I don't know what to do afterwards.

I have tried to use pandas multi-indexing, but couldn't quite understand it. How do I re-build my new CSV data object? Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

P.S. May I complete my question considering multiple indices. For example lets say we have added a column to the left hand of the table with date of purchase. How could this be handled?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an example of a [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) operation:

```
>>> df
  Customer Product  Quantity
0       C1      P1         2
1       C2      P1         3
2       C1      P2         4
3       C3      P2         1
4       C3      P1         0
5       C2      P2         5
>>> df.pivot(index="Customer", columns="Product", values="Quantity")
Product   P1  P2
Customer        
C1         2   4
C2         3   5
C3         0   1
```

The part of the documentation on [reshaping](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) is recommended reading.

(PS: I'm assuming your file actually has commas, even though you didn't show any-- otherwise `pd.read_csv` would need an extra argument, like `delim_whitespace=True` or something.)

Comment: Thanks, that's an answer.
May I complete my question considering multiple indices?
For example lets say we have added a column to the left hand of the table with date of purchase. How could this be handled? I guess stack is the answer but again I don't know how! Either I am dumb or the documentation is terrible!